# Web Service not working in ASP.NET WebForms ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, webforms

I'm trying to call a simple web service like this, on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/service/local/newsservice.asmx/DoPost", // "/news/post/do",
    data: {
        title: _title,
        markdown: _markdown,
        categoryId: 1
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success!");
    }
});
```

The actual service is:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://service.site.com/service/news")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class NewsService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void DoPost(string title, string markdown, int categoryId)
    {
        if (!(Roles.IsUserInRole("Owner") || Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")))
            return;

        CommunityNews.Post(title, markdown, categoryId);
    }
}
```

When using the rewritten URL, which points to `"/service/local/newsservice.asmx/DoPost"`, I get the following error:

> The HTTP verb POST used to access path
>   '/service/local/newsservice.asmx/DoPost' is not allowed.

When I use the plain URL, I get this instead (via Firebug, the application silently fails):

> DoPost Web Service method name is not valid.

What could be going on?

Comment: What happens when you debug and load your web service URL in a browser? Can you post data with the ASP.NET test pages?

Comment: have you tried removing the `[ScriptMethod]` attribute, using `[WebMethod]` means accepting the `POST` requests where as when you want to use `GET` you do something like `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpPost = true)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in way of calling a web service in ASP.NET is to use a service reference, which creates JavaScript objects for you to call your web service methods.

> [ServiceReference Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.servicereference.aspx)
>
> To call Web service methods from ECMAScript (JavaScript), you must
>   include a service reference in the ASP.NET page and apply the
>   ScriptServiceAttribute attribute to the Web service class definition.
>   If you include a service reference to a Web service in the
>   ScriptManager or ScriptManagerProxy control inside the ASP.NET page,
>   JavaScript objects will be instantiated in the browser.
>
> The proxy objects will be used to do the following:
>
> - Make asynchronous requests in JavaScript to Web service methods,
> - Initialize instances of proxies of server data types, in
>     particular for use as input parameters for invoking Web methods.

Since you're using jQuery instead of the proxy objects created for ASP.NET AJAX, you might have to check a couple things are configured properly:

> [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx)
>
> To enable Web service calls from [ASP.NET AJAX] script, you must register the
>   ScriptHandlerFactory HTTP handler in the application's Web.config
>   file. The handler processes calls made from script to .asmx Web
>   services. The following example shows the Web.config element for
>   adding the handler.
>
> > These configuration settings are already part of the Web.config file
> >     template for any new AJAX-enabled Web sites that you create in
> >     Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.
>
> ```
> <system.web>   
>   <httpHandlers>
>     <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/> 
>     <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" 
>       type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
>       validate="false"/>   
>   </httpHandlers> 
> <system.web>
> ```
>
> For Web service calls that are not issued from ASP.NET AJAX script,
>   the ScriptHandlerFactory handler delegates the call to the default
>   handler, which uses SOAP instead of JSON format. The delegation is
>   performed automatically and you do not have to take any action unless
>   you want to disable the use of the SOAP protocol for the Web services.
>   In that case, you must enter the following configuration setting in
>   the Web.config file.
>
> ```
> <system.web>   
>   <webServices>
>     <protocols>
>       <clear/>
>     </protocols>   
>   </webServices> 
> </system.web>
> ```

Comment: Following this post, I created a new service and tested from that one, it worked, a few attempts to make them similar later, I realized my method was static, because I had copied and pasted it from the web page it originally was in.

Comment: @Nico - That's a good point, and it makes sense! Web page methods decorated with the `PageMethod` attribute need to be static to be called from script, but web service methods should be ordinary public methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in using the

`[ScriptMethod]`

do you really need it here.

also check this may help:[ScriptMethod]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.71).aspx